# What does "$\land$" mean in $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m\land n}(-1)^k{m \choose k}{n \choose k}z_1^{m-k}z_2^{n-k}$?

Tags: summation, notation

What does the $\land$ mean in this sum?

$$
H_{m,n}(z_1,z_2) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m\land n}(-1)^k{m \choose k}{n \choose k}z_1^{m-k}z_2^{n-k}
$$

The formula is a definition of the complex Hermite polynomials. I saw it in the paper ["Analytic Properties of Complex Hermite Polynomials" (PDF link via AMS.org)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2016-368-02/S0002-9947-2015-06358-2/S0002-9947-2015-06358-2.pdf) by E. H. Ismail.

Comment: $m\wedge n$ is the (lattice) meet of $m$ and $n$.  Here you are probably using the usual linear order on $\mathbb{N}$ so $m\wedge n=\min(m,n)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not common notation, but $m \wedge n$ may be used to denote $\min\{m,n\}$: the smaller of the two integers. (Similarly, $m \vee n$ may be used to denote $\max\{m,n\}$.) This makes sense in context: we want $k \le m$ and $k \le n$ for the binomial coefficients $\binom mk$ and $\binom nk$ to make sense, and otherwise, we want $k$ to range as high as possible. If you are fine saying that $\binom nk = 0$ when $k>n$, then you can drop the upper bound on the summation and take a sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty$.

This notation is derived from the [join and meet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) operations on partially ordered sets. This is a more general idea. If $x$ and $y$ are two elements of a partially ordered set, then their meet $z = x \wedge y$ (if it exists) must satisfy

1. $z \le x$ and $z \le y$;
2. $w \le z$ for all elements $w$ such that $w \le x$ and $w \le y$.

If $\le$ is the usual ordering on real numbers, then $x \wedge y$ reduces to $\min\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. It is not so uncommon I would say.

Comment: I think it is less popular than actually writing out $\min\{m,n\}$.